# How do I traverse/iterate through all the objects inside a form in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB class inside which one of the methods accepts an array of forms.

For each form inside the array, I need it to traverse all of the objects, check if they are a specific tyoe (input, label, checkbox, etc.) and get the properties of each object. Then, I want to dump these into a text file in the following format:

```
Form1 | Label1 | "Enter your name"
```

"Enter your name" being the caption or text of the form object.

I want to do this to facilitate the translation of an application. Any ideas or thoughts you might have on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a For Each for the form's .Controls collection. However, note that if a child control of the form has more controls in its own .Controls collection, they won't be accounted for. You'll have to make a recursive function in order to traverse the whole parent-child chain of controls to find them all.

Now, for each control, you'll want to perhaps do a Case statement to check the Type Of for each control. Then cast the control to it's type and grab the properties.

Answer (score 3):

The following code will return an `IEnumerable(Of Control)` which contains all child controls of the passed in control.  It will recursively descend down the tree and get all nested controls.

```
Public Function GetAllControls(ByVal source as Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
  Dim seq = Enumerable.Empty(Of Control)
  For Each child in source.Controls 
    if child.Controls.Count > 0 Then
      seq = seq.Concat(GetAllControls(child))
    End If
  Next 
  Return seq
End Function
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you ever add to the seq collection. I think you need something like seq = seq.add(child) right after the For Each. Otherwise you will always get Nothing back right?

Comment: @sinDizzy look at the `seq = seq.Concat(...)` line.  this is adding to the sequence

Comment: But that's a recursive call. So the deeper you get into that loop, lets say the final loop, its not adding anything. The reason i say this is I tried it on my project and called it with (Me) as the control. Got Nothing back.

Comment: It was driving me crazy why I would get Nothing back. I tried this method and got a list of controls: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/549115/Howplustoplusfindplusallpluschildpluscontrolsplusf Very similar structure but there's that one extra line.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to be able to localise your form then a much simpler way would be to set the form's [Localizable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(VS.80).aspx) property to true. This will result in the creation of a .resx file containing all the values of the various properties for all the controls on the form so that the texts etc can be translated and distributed as a separate satellite assembly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ProcessForm(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessForm(ByVal frm As Form)
        For Each el As Control In frm.Controls
            Dim str As String
            str = String.Format("{0} | {1} | {2}", frm.Name.ToString(), el.Name.ToString(), el.Text.ToString())
            Debug.Print(str)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```